# Javascript GTK bindings

Tags: javascript, gtk, node.js

The Bindings for the GTK library in Javascript maintained by Gnome, are they asynchronous or synchronous calls? I have not been able to find details one way or the other.

I would like to develop a NodeJS module for GTK for desktop app creation.

Comment: No I have not, TBH, Sadly the requirements of the paying job outweighs the personal projects

Comment: logic clearly dictates that the needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few  -- spock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the start of static gtk bindings at https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-gtk and I'm starting bindings to GObject Introspection Repository at https://github.com/creationix/node-gir.  Both are incomplete.  Mine is just a roadmap at the moment, but I've worked out some good planning with people offline.

If you have a specific app in mind you want to build and it doesn't require many widgets, then it might be easiest to just add those bindings to Tim Smart's repo.  My GIR bindings, once complete will allow usage of pretty much any gnome library without having to keep bindings up to date.

Answer (score 1):

GTK is event loop based, so this should be possible. You'll have to integrate GMainLoop with node's main loop.

Comment: This makes sense I'm looking into it now.

Comment: let us know here if you have any advance on this topic.